# MVC, Render page with Angular and getting RouteParams from two URL's

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller

**EDIT:**

I have a solution build on MVC5, C#. I have two different views with the following URL's:

1. /Event/DetailsPublic/18 - (where 18 is the Id of the event) In this view I render the view below using angular.
2. /Aps/Card/18 - (where 18 is the Id of the event)

If I go to `/TournamentCards/` it redirects to `/Aps/Card/18` which I define in my routeProvider. Here I am also getting the Id into my scope by using routeParams. All of this is defined in an angular js file (module.js).

**module.js:**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/TournamentCards/:id', {
          templateUrl: '/Aps/Card.html'
      });

}]);
```

When I am at `/Aps/Card/18` which is an html file (Card.html) I get the Id into my scope in my app controller (cardController.js):

```
$scope.id = $routeParams.id;  // routeParams.id gives "18"
```

In the DetailsPublic.cshtml I am rendering the Card.html including the angular:

```
    <div ng-app="tournamentApp">
        <div ng-include src="'/Aps/Card.html'"></div>
    </div>
```

If I go to `/Event/DetailsPublic/18` the view works fine and renders all the js fine but I am not getting the routeParams. When I debug I can see that `$routeParams.id` is undefined.

If I add ng-view to the html above nothing is rendered and I am getting no errors in the consol.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you have 2 routes both leading to "/Aps/Card.html" and it's also included with `ng-include` always? I would try 2 things - remove `ng-include` and add `ng-view` instead of it - this should be rendered to route's template, when you navigate to it. Secondly, I would look for errors in console.

Comment: Hi Ilya, thank you for your reply. If I do the first thing you mention nothing is rendered from in the DetailsPublic. I am not getting any errors in the consol. :(

Comment: Hi again Ilya. I noticed a mistake in my code. It doenst make sence that I make two routings. I have editted my question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: I still can't understand what are you trying to do? Where do you set the `ng-controller` in your markup? Where is `ng-view`? Could you maybe create some jsfiddle or plunker with complete sample of your problem? P.S. Have you checked the [official sample](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example)?